# Deleting to previous full stop or comma

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way I can set up a short cut on Mac OSX such that it deletes till the previous full stop (or comma)?

Often while editing text documents or email, I want to delete the sentence I'm currently editing.  <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> removes the current line, <kbd>Opt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> deletes a single word, and <kbd>Fn</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> deletes forward.  Could I set up, say <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd>, to delete everything up to a previous specified punctuation?

thanks
Sathish

Comment: Are these system-wide shortcuts (if so, that's pretty neat), or are these shortcuts within a certain program?

Comment: @evilsoup System-wide in programs with 'native' UI (Firefox, Eclipse, MS Office, etc. might not implement them). You can also define custom [system-wide shortcuts for macro-like text editing actions](http://lri.me/keybindings.html) (for compliant apps), but it doesn't seem to cover sentences as a unit to act on.

Comment: @evilsoup Yes, system wide shortcuts please, if that be possible.  I can do it in vim with say dT. or dT: but I would like to have it in browsers, editors, email apps, etc.

Comment: @DanielBeck, didn't know about the KeyBindings settings until now.  Thanks!  If not this particular task, I definitely have use of it for others.